# PayPal Sandbox Vs Live IDs

Tags: paypal

Simple question:
After testing my pages in the PayPal Sandbox account with the Sandbox ID and getting success, **do I have to replace the Sandbox `<script>` ID with my Live `<script>` ID to go Live** on the web pages?

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AZkc3msMTVG13hih5aKum4T9iAfi2t_ZOS-bFB4I9.. Sandbox

<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AZXJHo2Qp14Diln5yFwIbYGV7gydOBtTzLJVX0ow2yzA.... Live
```

I used the top one for my testing, then when all was well, I replaced it with the bottom one, is that what I should've done? Anyone?
Just a yes or no would be extremely helpful, then maybe I could suss out the next step as all these Developer terms are beyond me!

Comment: Thank you, I'm grateful

Answer (score 0):

For a JS SDK integration, change the sandbox client-id to a live client-id . This might be all you need in your case. (Edit: having changed the formatting of your question so your `<script>` tags appear, I see that yes you're using the JS SDK so this is all you need to do)

---

For any other type of front-end web integration, change the 'business' parameter (if there is one) from a sandbox value to a live value, and change the website it posts or redirects to to not have `sandbox.` in the URL.

For backend API integrations, change the API credentials from sandbox to live, and the communication/redirect endpoints to not have `sandbox.` in the URL.